# Magento hacked even after applied patch

Tags: magento-1.8, patches, security

Some days before my Magento community edition 1.8.1 site is hacked, because we are late to apply the [patch](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/). we found certain files were changed those are

1. index.php [hackers added some code to it].
2. get.php
3. js/index.php
4. js/lib/ccard.js
5. lib/Varien/Autoload.php

And they also installed module called [Magpleasure file system](http://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/file-system/)

But after applying the patch, and removing all the stuff what hackers added in our application problem is not solved.

hackers eventually changing 3 files

1. get.php
2. js/index.php
3. js/lib/ccard.js

Is there anything that we are missing?

How to prevent them by attacking our files?

Is patch is working or not? How should I check that?

Comment: first check if the vulnerability is not on the hosting side (I don't know how to do that). Maybe you got hacked through other means other than Magento.

Comment: Yeah, We checked it by asking hosting team. they informed only we have ssh permission to it, we changed all the password too. but no use.

Comment: Are there any other applications on the same domain? Like WordPress or something? Maybe these were also compromised or they got in through these apps?

Comment: @7ochem, No, there are no other applications

Comment: Anna's suggestions are spot-on and you appear to have identified a few of the most common files modified.  We've documented all the ones we'v uncovered in our remediation efforts at https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit - please consider adding your own hard-won knowledge to the project by forking and submitting a pull request.

Comment: @BJHoffpauir, Sure I will do, thanks for inviting.

Answer (score 16):

It seems your Magento setup is still compromised at some point so you should carefully check Magento + Webserver settings.

You cannot trust your installation if it was compromised. The ultimate way to go would be a new & clean setup of all files on a new host with the latest backup before you shop was compromised.

If this is not possible due to various reasons, you might check/do these things related to this issue:

**Remove all detected changed/hacked files plus installed extensions**

Even better: Do a clean (git) checkout from your development system with the lastest version. This will be the safest unless your dev/staging system hasn't been compromised also (which is not the case if you develop locally or in a protected environment).

**Remove created backend admin accounts**

Especially for SUPEE-5344, there will also be an admin account created in the backend. Remove all new/unnecessarry admin accounts.

**Backup plan**

Depending on your backup plan and strategy, you could maybe think about a rollback of your complete database.

**Check file/folder permissions**

Did you check your file/folder permissions?
There's no need to run everything with 777 or as root user. Depending on your server configuration 400/500 can be enough. See [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html) here.

**Check server logs**

Check your webservers access/error log to trace accessed sites and suspicious URLs.
Maybe you find suspicious IP's to block on firewall level.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty usual I think. Patches come after Magento's security team discovers the vulnerability or someone reports it to them. But until then Magento stores remain a hackers' playground.

A few files to check which could have been modified too:

1. app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Checkout/Payment/Method/Ccsave.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
3. app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php
4. app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

Also, the following command comes handy in finding malware/backdoors/shell once you're SSH's in your server:

```
find /var/www -name "*.php" -exec grep -l "$_FILES[" {} \;
```

I took the above info from https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/how-to-remove-fix-magento-opencart-credit-card-malware-hack/

Might be useful to check directly.