# Site was hacked and placed a linked on the bottom of my website

Tags: magento-1.9, security, link

Recently my website was hacked and at the bottom of the page there is a link that gets redirected to spam. I looked at every file that is associated with my site as well as used the built in debug path hint and I am unable to find this link. When looking through all my code especially my footer.phtml this random link is not present. When I view the debug for the frontend the path hint stops before this link.

I have notice is on the footer on every page as well as the admin page. Has anyone encounter this before. My website is http://www.supermarketneeds.com and you can see a link under the footer called Mature.

Thank you

Comment: The link looks like it's after about everything, have you checked index.php? also, have you clicked it? It is on NSFW content on your domain, presumably in your magento folder... the link is one of the smaller problems I guess... Have you installed the latest patches?

Comment: Check your CMS block/pages.

Comment: I clicked the linked and discover it was a folder on my server called Mature.  When I view index.php (which I assume in in the main file directory before you click the app folder I do not see anything inside. The programer who designed the website said I am unable to install the latest patch due to he create the website over the main skin @simonthesorcerer

Comment: nothing is in the block/pages @mbalparda

Comment: do you have an idea of where this can be? @simonthesorcerer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments:

1st: get another programmer :) He is right that the patches can not be applied (in other words: "have to be applied manually which is not funny") when he build on the `base/default`-package, but he just never should have done this.

2nd: your shop has been hacked and the link on the bottom is the smallest problem. You can check here: https://www.magereport.com/ to which of the latest hacks your shop is vulnerable.

3rd: Here is a short list what you should check for immediately: [Magento hacked even after applied patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67660/magento-hacked-even-after-applied-patch/67669#67669) and here is an even longer list: https://github.com/comitdevelopers/magento-security-toolkit

4th: Sorry, but I can not tell you exactly what is wrong with your shop. It may even be an issue that the whole server has been compromised. You or your new programmer will have to look into this.