# Strange Includes Errors in Magento system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, error, security, system.log

I'm getting these strange includes in my system log file. I 
Grep searched all database and all files on my website and can't find any of these weird file names:

```
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
2015-12-27T15:00:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Z6zjfr/Jinhp4muczl4tybbkadnpceg5cbm/7v/30pjzcdms0.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/local:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/community:/home/angeecom/public_html/app/code/core:/home/angeecom/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php')  in /home/angeecom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56
```

Any ideas about what this could be or if something is trying to hack me?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you've been hacked, indeed. Not "trying", because this must come from malicious php code that's already on your server. But it might also come from an obfuscated extension that's not (de)installed completely

Comment: So what would you suggest as a possible solution?

Comment: @Freejoy: Check out my answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/67669/231

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it is a hack. I found the module responsible for the errors. It's a email marketing module. I was testing it and every time the cron starts this error happens. I was going to come back here and tell about it, but I haven't found the exact place where the module causes this error. For one thing whatever it is it dosen't seem to be working for the "hacker" as it fails to include. I'm suspicious thou. But I really like the email module hate to let it go. :)

Comment: Just an update on this. I found the problem. It was a custom email template I added to the module. When I deleted the template the error went away.